# Urdu Language Support for sending email to hotmail and yahoo with phpmailer

Tags: unicode, phpmailer, hotmail, yahoo-mail, urdu

I am using phpmailer to send my auto-generated text/mail to users. body of the mail contains Urdu (Unicode), which is shown by google perfectly, but hotmail and yahoo mail shows the mail as shown in the following snapshot:

[image]

is this a bug or i am missing any Unicode supporting parameter for sending my emails-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that your code tells PHPMailer to use UTF-8:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

Note that the property name `CharSet` is case-sensitive, so ensure it matches exactly. You must also ensure that your content in also UTF-8 format.

Comment: This an awesome and pretty good solution man, thanks @Synchro